# useEffect using old variable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the below code, I expect it to run

> start of useEffect
>
> false
>
> cleanup
>
> start of useEffect
>
> true

but it instead returns this, where isCanceled is still false even after the cleanup

> start of useEffect
>
> false
>
> cleanup
>
> start of useEffect
>
> false

The code is this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("start of useEffect")
    let isCanceled = false;
    console.log(isCanceled);

    return () => {
      isCanceled = true;
      console.log("cleanup");
    };
  });
```

Why is it still false even after cleanup? I was following this article for your reference https://dev.to/pallymore/clean-up-async-requests-in-useeffect-hooks-90h

Tried to reread article and google this question, but not sure why still.

Comment: You're logging `isCancelled` right after it's created as `false`. No code can run in between, so it's still `false`. The pattern in the article you linked is only useful if you're running something asynchronous, and you check `isCancelled` after that async thing finishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanup will change 'isCanceled' for previous callBack if not resolved yet. It won't affect the new callBack, as it is within useEffect callBack scope.

[After every re-render with changed dependencies, React will first run the cleanup function (if you provided it) with the old values, and then run your setup function with the new values. After your component is removed from the DOM, React will run your cleanup function](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters)

There are scenarios where useEffect might be called multiple times, even if it is supposed to run only once with an empty array of dependencies []. The cleanup function will be called every time useEffect is triggered again and could help to avoid multi-call side effects.

In the example below, the result of the first request will be ignored:

callDelay is changed by setCallDelay(6000) in if (!count) which triggered useEffect before the first request is delivered.

```
const request = async (callDelay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("done!");
    }, callDelay);
  });
};

let count;
const App = () => {
  const [callDelay, setCallDelay] = useState(5000);

  if (!count) {
    count = 1;
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCallDelay(6000);
    }, 1000);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    let isCanceled = false;

    request(callDelay).then((result) => {
      if (!isCanceled) {
        console.log(result);
      } else {
        console.log("Too late!, result arrived but meanwhile useEffect was called again.");
      }
    });

    return () => {
      isCanceled = true;
    };
  }, [callDelay]);

  return <Text>Called with {callDelay} ms delay</Text>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you've got it wrong.

`isCanceled` is a ***local*** variable to every `useEffect` run. It's not shared between runs of the `useEffect` callback.

The cleanup function of the `useEffect` only sets the `isCanceled` variable **in it's local scope** to false.

The running of the cleanup function doesn't affect the local variable `isCanceled` of any other run of the callback passed to `useEffect`